# Script from TypeScript was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“video/mp2t”)

Tags: typescript, mime-types, mime

I'm trying to run a TypeScript file,the only code in the file is `console.log("test")`
i sourced it to a boiler plate HTML file,but when i try to execute in a live server with the VSC Live Server extention i get the error message:
`Script from **file** was blocked because of a disallowed MIME type (“video/mp2t”)`

I have searched everywhere and no solution works for me,help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Found the solution,turns out i just needed to use the `tsc` command to compile to JavaScript

Answer (score 2):

It also happens when you are linking .ts file with html, instead of .js file.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30922315)

Answer (score -1):

fix this by add some code to karma.conf.js

```
 mime: {
  'text/x-typescript': ['ts','tsx']
}
```

Comment: Nothing happened,do i add this to the TS file or HTML file?